# What happens when I inherit from an instance instead of a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance

I'm just curious what will happen when I inherit an instance into a class.

So I tried:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def print(self):
        print(self.x)

def inherit(obj):
    class Child(obj): # Line 20
        pass  # or maybe added functionality

    return Child

param = 5
x = X(param)
y = inherit(x) # Line 27
y.print()
```

I get (at least) the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    y = inherit(x)
  File "/test.py", line 20, in inherit
    class Child(obj):
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I just wonder: **Is inheriting an instance anything meaningful/useful or just plain nonsense?**

(The question is a bit academic and specifically about the details of inheriting an instance. It's not about alternatives like object delegation or general design practices.)

Answer (score 13):

Classes are just like instances; they have a *type*. For instances that type is the class, but for classes, the type is called a *metaclass*. Inheriting from a class normally would call the metatype of the base class to produce a new class object (using `type(base)`; for multiple bases restrictions apply). The standard metatype is the `type` object, but you can [create your own metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).

By inheriting from an instance, Python tries to create a new class by calling `type(obj)(classname, bases, body_namespace)`.  Since `type(obj)` is `X` and `X.__init__()` doesn't support those arguments, the call fails. However, there is nothing stopping you from making that part work!

```
>>> class X:
...     def __init__(self, classname, parents, namespace):
...         print('Creating {}{}'.format(classname, parents))
...
>>> class Child(X('X', (), {})): pass
...
Creating X()
Creating Child(<__main__.X object at 0x10372b4a8>,)
>>> Child
<__main__.X object at 0x10372b470>
>>> Child()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'X' object is not callable
```

Of course, `type` provides a lot more functionality that a class won't offer out of the box; there are a series of descriptors to provide attributes on a class that other parts of Python expect to exist. Your class would have to cover all of those instead; in the above sample output, you'll note that `repr(Child)` produces `<__main__.X object at 0x...>` rather than the expected `<class '__main__.Child'>`, and there is no `__call__` method to produce instances for the class. So using an instance as a base class for another *can* work, you just have to put in the extra work to define all that expected functionality.

In the end, using an instance as a base class may be possible, but has no *practical* uses, not when any of the use-cases are already covered by metaclasses instead.

Answer (score -3):

Python has, under the hood, a protoype-based model of object-oriented design. This means that everything, even classes, are objects in the Pythonic world.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming

The relationship of inheritance in Python is carried out via a reference in the instance that signals its class. This is **class**. You can change this reference to any other class during runtime. If you do it to change the behaviour of the instance at runtime, then you are implementing dynamic inheritance. For example, think of an instance of a list of one element, the **ListOfOne** class, which has appropriate methods to deal with just one element. If another element was added, then the **class** reference could change to **RegularList**. If the list was emptied, then its class could change to **EmptyList**.

Unfortunately (or not) Python hides all of this. For example, you create your prototypes under the class label, and some operations that could be perfectly legal under this view are prohibited. Thus, it would be possible to inherit from an instance, but Python denies the possibility.

Comment: Python does **not** use the prototype-based model; Python is very firmly a [class-based system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming). That classes are themselves objects does not define a system as prototype based, you misunderstood how that model works. And Python does not deny the possibility to inherit from an instance either.

Comment: While classes do happen to be objects, Python is not prototype-based.

Comment: The Wikipedia article even contrasts Prototype-based systems with class-based systems in that the latter *usually* won't let you alter the classes at runtime, then names Python as one of the exceptions to that limitation of class-based systems.