# How to place class in its own file when it appears to be inheriting from an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, pony, ponyorm

**Background**: I'm using this guide; [Pony Orm](https://docs.ponyorm.com/firststeps.html). It tells me to create an object (db = Database()), then create a class that inherits from db (class Person(db.Entity)....). As far as I can tell, Person is inheriting from an instance - I didn't even know that was possible. If it is possible, I don't know how to put the Person class in another file, since all entities would need the same db object, but I don't instantiate the db object until runtime (yet I'm creating them at design time). I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

```
db = Database()
class Person(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    age = Required(int)
    cars = Set('Car')
```

**Questions**: (1st) In the example given, is Person really inheriting from an instance(db) or is something else going on? (2nd) How would I put the Person (and other classes) in its own file and share the db instance?

Note: I'm running Python 3.4.

**[EDITs]**

```
print(type(db.Entity)) # yields: <class 'pony.orm.core.EntityMeta'>
```

Comment: While `db` is an instance, `db.Entity` could be either an instance property or a class property. It seems likely that `db.Entity` is an instance property that is a dynamic class which references other instance properties. It's hard to pick this apart without diving into the source code, but a `print(type(db.Entity))` may reveal something.

Comment: Sharing the instance of `db` may be as simple as instantiating it in one file and importing it in others.

Comment: @JaredGoguen thank you for the response...so would that file be something like (db_creator), that all of my entities import, and the helper class that uses the enities?

Comment: Yeah, something like that. You might have to take care that each import isn't instantiating a new `db` object (I don't think it will) but this is easy to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Of course it's not possible to inherit from an instance. `db` may be an instance of `Database`, but `db.Entity` (which you're inheriting from) is very much a class. If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/blob/orm/pony/orm/core.py#L531) you can see that it's a dynamically created class:

   `self.Entity = type.__new__(EntityMeta, 'Entity', (Entity,), {})`
2. If you don't instantiate the `db` variable until runtime, this is tricky. You have to choose: either instantiate `db` at program startup and define your `Person` class as usual, or postpone the class definition until the `db` instance is created. Generally speaking it's never a good idea to create classes during runtime, so I would recommend instantiating `db` right away.

   Splitting this into multiple files however is easy. In file A.py you instantiate the `db`:

   `db = Database()`

   And in B.py you simply import A:

   `from A import db
   class Person(db.Entity):`

Comment: Technically, [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361402/5014455) to inherit from an instance that isn't a class (all classes are instances of a metaclass, after all!), but it isn't particularly useful.

Comment: Wow, I feel like I will never master Python - thank you for the quick response. I'll use your import suggestion.